# Change TFS Work Item Type

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, tfs-workitem

Is it possible to change the type of a TFS work item? For example, I have a Bug I would like to change to a Change Request.

Comment: What process template are you using?

Comment: I think its a custom template based on MSF for Agile Software Development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not easily.  You could try and hack the database, but that's really not a good idea.  Just like dancing barefoot in a room full of broken glass whilst juggling live grenades isn't a good idea.

I'd suggest you create a new work item for the change request, link it to the bug and then set the bug state to obsolete/closed.

Comment: What if the bug already had changesets checked in against it? Will those somehow be linked to the new work item?

Comment: Not automatically, no.  You can always do it manually and add those linkages as well at the same time you link the change request to the bug.

It's a pain, but there's no easy way around it.

Comment: I have requested this feature here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/580662/ability-to-change-a-tfs-work-item-type

Comment: Uservoice request: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2037645-provide-the-ability-to-convert-a-work-item-to-a-di

Answer (score 22):

As noted you cannot directly change the work item type however there is a nice shortcut that may save you a lot of time for these scenarios.  It will automatically copy links to change sets, test cases etc.

1. Right-click on your workitem and select "Create Copy of Work Item"
2. The following dialog window will pop up where you can then **change the work item type** for the new item:

[image]

**Result:** A new work item is created with the **new type** and the old one automatically added as a link and a comment added to the history area stating the work item ID it was copied from..

Comment: This is the correct way, duplicate the work item and mark "removed" the previous one

Answer (score 0):

Changing a work item's type is now possible by right-clicking the work item in the web view and choosing Change Type:

[image]

[image]

Here's the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type) referenced in the screenshot above.

Answer (score -3):

Possible at least in TFS 2012, don't now about 2010

```
witadmin renamewitd /collection:”http://tfs-server-name:8080/tfs/collection-name
/p:Project-Name /n:”Product Backlog Item” /new:Story
```

Comment: This will change the name of the work item type. They are asking if it is possible to change type of an work item instance.

Comment: It is not what OP asked about