# TFS 2010: Change 'Work Item' type from 'Product Backlog Item' to 'Task' - how to?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I want to change the *type* of a 'Work Item' in TFS 2010: I entered a Work Item to the Product Backlog (we're using a Scrum template), and then I entered several 'Child' tasks, but I entered them as 'Product Backlog Items'. I should have entered them as 'Tasks'. How can I change them to appear as Tasks - children of the original 'Work Item'.

A previous question: [Change TFS Work Item Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586063/change-tfs-work-item-type)

would suggest that this is not simple. Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change TFS Work Item Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586063/change-tfs-work-item-type)

Comment: The situation remains unchanged, it's still not really possible to change types. http://juristr.com/blog/2009/08/howto-changing-tfs-workitem-type-from/

Comment: At current i believe the the only option is to recreate the items and migrate the data (not counting hacks in sql data), there are migration tools available, not sure if they cover migration to same tfs.

And there is always the Tfs api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change TFS Work Item Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586063/change-tfs-work-item-type)

Answer (score 12):

@PortageMonkey's answer to the question you quote contains pretty much what you need.

> As noted you cannot directly change the work item type however there
> is a nice shortcut that may save you a lot of time for these
> scenarios. It will automatically copy links to change sets, test cases
> etc.
>
> 1. Right-click on your work item and select "Create Copy of Work Item"
> 2. The following dialog window will pop up where you can then change the work item type for the new item:
>    [image: Screenshot of the dialog showing work item type options]
>    Result: A new work item is
>    created with the new type and the old one automatically added as a
>    link and a comment added to the history area stating the work item ID
>    it was copied from.

So, use this feature to copy them and convert them to tasks at the same time by choosing "task" in the copy dialog. Once the copy is done, flag the original item to "removed".

Comment: For those who are wondering where to find the window from the screenshot above: You have to open a Query in Visual Studio. You will see a List of Backlog Items then. Rightclick the one you want to copy, choose "Create Copy of Work Item..." and there you go. (Tested with Visual Studio Professional 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Changing a work item's type is now possible by right-clicking the work item in the web view and choosing Change Type:

[image]

[image]

Here's the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type) referenced in the screenshot above.